# Android Studio: Error: Error:(205, 24) error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I am very new to Android Studio. I am trying to build some Sqlite3 wrapper classes (written in C++). I tried to build them with NDK using Android studio, but I am getting error that "Error:(205, 24) error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable". I am not able to find what option should I give in gradle.build file. I have seen many posts but they all refer to some Android.mk or Application.mk file. I have pasted content of my gradle.build file below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asite.ndksample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk{
            moduleName "myLib"
            stl "gnustl_static"
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Let me know how to come out from this error using Android Studio with gradle.build file. Also let me know detail about all parameters mentioned under "ndk" section. I am not aware what all possible values can be put there.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the cFlags parameter under the ndk section:

```
ndk{
    moduleName "myLib"
    stl "gnustl_static"
    cFlags "-fexceptions"
}
```

The only other paramters you can use for this ndk configuration are `ldLibs` and `abiFilter`, to specify respectively required ndk libs (log...) and cpu architectures to compile for (x86, armeabi-v7a, x86_64...).